# What does that select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I am reading this code:
and I am wondering what does that **$('[placeholder]')** selector do?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
            $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                    input.removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            }).blur(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('placeholder');
                    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                }
            }).blur();
            $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
                $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val('');
                    }
                })
            });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It selects all elements with a `placeholder` attribute.](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Also, please do not use this code. It will not work properly e.g. in case of JS using `.val()` to get the field's value. It also won't allow the user to enter a value that's equal to the placeholder string. There are better scripts out there, e.g. this one: https://github.com/diy/jquery-placeholder